# Most efficient way to exclude questions asked by blocked users in Django app

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Q&A app that allows users to block/hide other users they find annoying or offensive. When a current_user views all questions – Question.objects.all() – I would like to exclude from the queryset all questions asked by users that have been blocked by current_user – Block.objects.filter(user_is_blocking=current_user)

What’s the most efficient way to do this? If it makes a difference to your answer, I’ll be applying the same exclusion list to other models, like Answers, that also include User as a FK.

Models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    question = models.CharField()

class Block(models.Model):
    user_is_blocking = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_blocking")
    user_is_blocked = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_blocked")
```

UPDATE:
I got this working thanks to sk1p. I then wanted to make the exclude bi-directional - so I only see questions from users I have not blocked AND who have not blocked me. I did that as follows for anyone interested in combining subqueries:

```
from itertools import chain

i_am_blocking = User.objects.filter(user_blocked__user_is_blocking=request.user)
is_blocking_me = User.objects.filter(user_blocking__user_is_blocked=request.user) 
blocked_users = list(chain(i_am_blocking, is_blocking_me))

questions = Question.objects.exclude(user__in=blocked_users)
...
```

Comment: using `list(chain(qs))` works, but you are no longer using a subquery, you are doing an `IN (1, 2, 3, ...)` query, with all the user IDs. If you use this with larger querysets, you get some communication and query parsing overhead. You can do `i_am_blocking | is_blocking_me` to get the same result with a subquery, or you can chain `.exclude()` calls: `Question.objects.exclude(user__in=i_am_blocking).exclude(user__in=is_blocking_me)`

Comment: Thanks. Your latter example of chaining works. Is that still executing a subquery? What would my syntax be for using 'i_am_blocking | is_blocking_me'? of the two options, which do you prefer and why? Appreciate your help.

Comment: I think using chained `exclude()` calls, you get two subqueries. `i_am_blocking | is_blocking_me` is the queryset that contains both te blocked and the blocking users, and you use it in the `__in` lookup: `Question.objects.exclude(user__in=i_am_blocking | is_blocking_me)`. To find out what SQL is generated, either use django-debugtoolbar or, in a python shell, `from django.db import connection`, `print connection.queries`

Comment: I don't really prefer one or the other, I mostly use what is more readable in the situation at hand

Comment: using this example model, how can I add new blocked user for the current user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `__in` field lookup:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    question = models.CharField()

class Block(models.Model):
    user_blocking = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="blocks_set")
    user_blocked = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="blocks_received")

blocked_users = User.objects.filter(blocks_received__user_blocking=current_user)
questions = Question.objects.exclude(user__in=blocked_users)
```

(I took the liberty of renaming your related names and fields to understand the problem better, you don't have to change your names of course...)

The `__in` lookup will be translated into a subquery, so the database will do most of the work.

The actual performance then depends on your database. The Django documentation [warns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#in) about bad optimization by MySQL, in particular, so I'd recommend running the resulting query against a copy of your production database, and have a look at the query plan with `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (on PostgreSQL).

If the subquery-based approach doesn't work well with your database, you can rewrite it as a raw SQL query and compare performance:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM app_question q,
auth_user author

LEFT JOIN app_block b ON (b.user_blocked_id = author.id)
LEFT JOIN auth_user ON (b.user_blocking_id = auth_user.id AND auth_user.id = %s)

WHERE author.id = q.user_id AND auth_user.id IS NULL;
```

[Proof-of-concept SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!10/f4dfd/9)

The idea is to join the block table to the question's author, and if one exists, discard the question. The `%s` is the parameter for the current user's id; be sure to [not use string formatting!](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw)

Comment: How about if I want to make it bi-directional? So I exclude questions where the author is blocked by me AND has blocked me themselves?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, do something like `blocking_users = User.objects.filter(blocks_set__user_blocked=current_user)` and then `.exclude()` that from your `Question` set, too

Comment: using this example model, how can I add new blocked user for the current user?